# PHP download attachment via HTTP

Tags: php, file, download

I have a website which is letting me download data; by this I mean when I point a browser to it the browser starts downloading a document. In other words,

I want to be able to get that document.

I have tried doing a file_get_contents of the URL, and also tried a basic cURL to the URL, neither have resulted in the actual file (cURL example I did have CURL_RETURNTRANSFER set to 1).

Anyway, any ideas?

```
$ch = curl_init();

// set url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//return the transfer as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// $output contains the output string
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// close curl resource to free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Maybe try wget on command shell?

Comment: So just to get this right: the URL you have works in the browser but does not work with cUrl?

Comment: And what have your tries resulted in? Dancing clowns on the screen? Maybe you also should add some code you used.

Comment: $output just ends up being false. I figured it out though after looking at curl_error. Just some SSL stuff I need to pay attention to.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at curl_error I found there was an SSL protocol error, I can simple add the option to ignore that and it works like a champ. Thought there was something more complicated going on...